# Windows 8 sometimes forgets how to open a file and does the wrong thing

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I have this really irritating problem with my Windows 8.1 PC.  Occasionally, like maybe one time in ten, when I double click on a file or folder to open it nothing will happen.  Sometimes the wrong thing will happen and it launches grepwin, or 7-zip.  Sometimes I'll get a popup with an error message.  There's no rhyme or reason to it and it happens sporadically but when it does happen it will happen maybe three or four times and then the right thing will happen.

Here's a screengrab of what my right-click context menu usually looks like.
[image: Normal context menu]

When things go wrong, it can look like this:
[image: Weird context menu #1]

Or maybe this:
[image: Weird context menu #2]

I've even had one that only had "Cut", "Copy" and "Paste" as options but haven't managed to grab it.  There's nothing obviously up from looking in eventvwr, so what's going on here?

Comment: There is a specific number of context menu options that Windows supports.  You are close to that number.  Once you exceed that number behavior is undefined.

Comment: That's interesting.  What's the magic number?

Comment: It's either 10 or 15, I forget the exact number, and don't have the time (at this moment) to google for the exact number